# How to overlay shapes or icon at the bottom of Tradingview price chart using Pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

What is a way to use Pinescript to add an overlay of icons or shapes at the bottom of the Tradingview price chart similar to how Event chart settings for dividends, splits, earnings, and news are displayed? Additionally, being able to mouse over the icon to display a brief summary of what that event is.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing you can do is using the `location` parameter with the `plotshape()` or `plotchar()` functions. For example:

```
//@version=5
strategy("Template strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

longCondition = ta.crossover(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

shortCondition = ta.crossunder(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)


plotchar(longCondition, text = "Long", char='', location = location.bottom, size = size.small)
plotchar(shortCondition, text = "Short", char='', location = location.bottom, size = size.small)
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the `plotshape()` and `location` doesn't go all the way to the bottom of that screen and also don't allow for mouseover text displays. `label.new()` and `label.set_tooltip()` helps with mouseover text display but can only be shown relative to bars instead of the display window.

Comment: Unfortunately that is true. That's why I mentioned this is the closest thing (to get to the bottom of the screen, which was your main question)

Answer (score 0):

The closest solution was not using an overlay and make the indicator right below the main chart and using `label.new()` and `label.set_tooltip()` to generate the popup text for different bars.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © thomastthai
// @version=5
    
indicator('Events', overlay=false, scale=scale.right, max_lines_count=500)
event1UnixTime = 1651687200000 
event1Label = label.new(x=event1UnixTime, xloc=xloc.bar_time, y=0, color=color.green, size=size.tiny)
label.set_tooltip(id=event1Label, tooltip="Event 1")
event2UnixTime = 1661687200000
event2Label = label.new(x=event2UnixTime, xloc=xloc.bar_time, y=0, color=color.red, size=size.tiny)
label.set_tooltip(id=event2Label, tooltip="Event 2")
```

[image]